# Captcha php code missing?

Tags: php, recaptcha

I'm a newbie here so hope I am posting in the right place! I have only the most basic understanding of code & tecnical issues in general so I hope I can explain this....

I am trying to implement a captcha on the form on my website to stop bots attacking it. I'm using this:

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php

I created a test php file for the client side and implemented the widget on the form successfully.

I also created a verify.php file for the server side, however I am unclear about what to input in the verify.php file where the instructions (as per link above) say to in **bold**:

```
if (!$resp->is_valid) {

**// What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly**

   die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .

        "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");

} else {

 **// Your code here to handle a successful verification**
```

The instructions says the following, but I don't understand what to input where.

In the code above:
recaptcha_check_answer returns an object that represents whether the user successfully completed the challenge.

If $resp->is_valid is true then the captcha challenge was correctly completed and you should continue with form processing.

If $resp->is_valid is false then the user failed to provide the correct captcha text and you should redisplay the form to allow them another attempt. In this case $resp->error will be an error code that can be provided to recaptcha_get_html. Passing the error code makes the reCAPTCHA control display a message explaining that the user entered the text incorrectly and should try again.

Any help much appreciated!

Thanks a lot.
Mark

Comment: You plug in how you want to handle a successful/unsuccessful verification, for example displaying an error message, or redirecting the person to the page they needed to solve a captcha to access.

Comment: a redirect to the page where the captcha was filled, with an error message please fill in the right text you see in the image or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

**// What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly** -> under this, there should be something like redirecting the user back to the form page with a message stating that he didn't fill the captcha correctly.

**// Your code here to handle a successful verification** -> under this, submit your contact form normally.

That's a working code on my website:

```
$publickey = "YOUR PUBLIC KEY HERE";
$privatekey = "YOUR PRIVATE KEY";
$resp = null;
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                              $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                              $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                              $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

if($resp->is_valid){
    // under this, submit your contact form normally.
}
else {
    header("Location: page_where_the_user_was.php?error=1");
            die();
}
```

Comment: OK thank you very much. I think I'm more confused now though! So I need to put some new code in? Or input something that was in the instructions at the bottom in my original question?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$resp->is_valid) {

**// What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly**

   die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .

        "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");

} else {

 **// Your code here to handle a successful verification**

echo "Login succesfull"; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply! :-) I added the code but it is still doing the same thing, which is that it is possible to proceed to the next page even if the words put into captcha are wrong. :-(

Comment: This is all the code:   <?php
  require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "6Le7a-ESAAAAAKh52DMHnPYdOoRTYDk4cqyGKWS2";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
   
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
         "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
  } else {

  
echo "Login succesfull"; }


  }
  ?>

Answer (score 0):

This is including a redirect to the page where they need to fill in the captcha again.
Hope it helped you out.

```
    if (!$resp->is_valid) {

    **// What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly**

    header('Location: index.php');
   **// Or test.php, I don't know the name of your page

       die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .

            "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");

    } else {

     **// Your code here to handle a successful verification**

    echo "Login succesfull"; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I input your code and inserted the correct redirect page, but the form still completes successfully whether the words entered in captcha are correct or not :-(

Comment: @Marijke please next time edit your answer at the place of creating a new one. Thanks

Comment: Thank you again for your help, I think I'm getting there! Sorry for these dumb questions but I have two...a) where is says "**// Your code here to handle a successful verification**" - does that mean I need some code for this line? What would it look like? b) further up in the code in the same file it says "$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]" - does that mean I need to put my server address in? Thanks for your patience :-)